# AWS Java SDK access cognito pool from another account

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I need to access a cognito pool using a user which exists in another account. (I need to do it from java.)
The user has access rights to this cognito pool but the Java SDK tries to use a non existing cognito pool from the same account where the user was created. I don't see any option to modify the target account.

So to be a bit more concrete.
I have account **111111111111**:
with user **arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/my-user**

And account **222222222222**:
with cognito pool: **arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:222222222222:userpool/my-user-pool-id**

However, the SDK is trying to access to a wrong(non existing) cognito pool in its own account: **arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:111111111111:userpool/my-user-pool-id**

The exception I got:

> com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderException: User: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/my-user is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminGetUser on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:111111111111:userpool/my-user-pool-id because no identity-based policy allows the cognito-idp:AdminGetUser action (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 393afe3c-e7cd-4c1c-b867-d15e3c50e38a)

The code:

```
AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoClient = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("eu-west-1").build();
    
AdminGetUserRequest adminGetUserRequest = (new AdminGetUserRequest()).withUserPoolId("my-user-pool-id").withUsername("a cognito username");
    
AdminGetUserResult adminGetUserResult = cognitoClient.adminGetUser(adminGetUserRequest);
```

I checked all of the parameters of the cognito client and the request but non of them seems to be the right one. Is there anyway to configure here the target account?

(I know the best/simplest solution would be to use users created in the same account's IAM where the cognito pool was created. However, it is not possible (not allowed) in our setup.)

Comment: Is `my-user` from account 111111111111 trying to assume a role from account 222222222222? Take a look at this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_aws-accounts.html) for context on what I am asking. Also, which version of the Java SDK are you using?

Comment: Exactly that what I'm trying to do. However, I don't have the option to set that the cognito user pool (my-user-pool-id) is in account 222222222222. The sdk automatically assumes that the pool is also in account 111111111111.

I'm using com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp:jar:1.11.415.

Comment: The error says `arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/my-user is not authorized`. If you have correctly assumed role it should have said `arn:aws:sts::222222222222:assumed-role/Rolename is not authorized`. If you fix that, it will probably fix your main issue as well since the SDK must be assuming the user pool is in the same account as the authenticated IAM principal. If that doesn't work, you can also try specifying the full ARN (`arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:222222222222:userpool/my-user-pool-id`) instead of just `my-user-pool-id`

Comment: The role assuming is done by the sdk and I don't know how to tell it to use the specific role I want. 
I tried to specify the full arn instead of the pool id. However, then it tries to assume the non existing role: "rn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:111111111111:userpool/arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:222222222222:userpool/my-user-pool-id"

Is there any way I can do it with the sdk?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/AuthUsingTempSessionToken.html Take a look at this example. In your code you will have to create a STS client, make an assume role request, and then use the temporary credentials generated to build the AWSCognitoIdentityProvider client.